# why thread don't work accurately (a count down with thread)

Tags: android, multithreading

I need count down timer that whenever I clicked or times up, send result and time score to another activity. So I used thread, but I don't know why in first time run activity it don't show time for some seconds in textview, one more strange thing is that when press back,then go to activity again it works fine.

count down code:

```
    if (flagTime) {
        flagTime = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int counter = 60;
                while (function.isActivityVisible() && counter > 0) {
                    counter--;
                    final int finalCounter = counter;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        G.HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (function.isActivityVisible()) {

                                    timeSc=finalCounter;
                                    String preSec = "";
                                    if (finalCounter < 10) {
                                        preSec = "0";
                                    }

                                    if (function.isActivityVisible()
                                            && finalCounter <= 0) {
                                        flagTime = false;
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                                Memorize.this,
                                                MemorizeResult.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("TIME", 60);
                                        intent.putExtra("ARRAY_RESULT",
                                                array_choice);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }

                                    String score = "00:" + preSec
                                            + finalCounter;
                                    txt[20].setText( " time ramaining " + score);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (!function.isActivityVisible()) {
                    flagTime = false;
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

I use many flag to handle it, but it seems don't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Something like:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```